# Permission exception for Sqoop

Tags: hdfs, file-permissions, sqoop, hortonworks-data-platform

Stack : Installed HDP-2.3.2.0-2950 using Ambari 2.1

The installation was auto. as the machines(total 9 nodes) had Internet connectivity and was done using root credentials.

An ls command output for reference(**sqoop user IS missing**) :

```
[root@l1031lab ~]# hadoop fs -ls /user
Found 7 items
drwx------   - accumulo  hdfs          0 2015-11-05 14:03 /user/accumulo
drwxrwx---   - ambari-qa hdfs          0 2015-10-30 16:08 /user/ambari-qa
drwxr-xr-x   - hcat      hdfs          0 2015-10-30 16:17 /user/hcat
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs      hdfs          0 2015-11-11 10:09 /user/hdfs
drwx------   - hive      hdfs          0 2015-11-06 09:42 /user/hive
drwxrwxr-x   - oozie     hdfs          0 2015-11-05 12:53 /user/oozie
drwxrwxr-x   - spark     hdfs          0 2015-11-05 13:59 /user/spark
[root@l1031lab ~]#
[root@l1031lab ~]#
```

Another worrisome(sqoop user IS missing) output when I thought about the user groups :

```
cat /etc/group
root:x:0:
bin:x:1:bin,daemon
daemon:x:2:bin,daemon
sys:x:3:bin,adm
adm:x:4:adm,daemon
tty:x:5:
disk:x:6:
lp:x:7:daemon
mem:x:8:
kmem:x:9:
wheel:x:10:
mail:x:12:mail
uucp:x:14:
man:x:15:
games:x:20:
gopher:x:30:
video:x:39:
dip:x:40:
ftp:x:50:
lock:x:54:
audio:x:63:
nobody:x:99:
users:x:100:oozie,ambari-qa,tez,falcon
dbus:x:81:
utmp:x:22:
utempter:x:35:
floppy:x:19:
vcsa:x:69:
cdrom:x:11:
tape:x:33:
dialout:x:18:
haldaemon:x:68:haldaemon
ntp:x:38:
saslauth:x:76:
mailnull:x:47:
smmsp:x:51:
stapusr:x:156:
stapsys:x:157:
stapdev:x:158:
sshd:x:74:
tcpdump:x:72:
slocate:x:21:
ovirtagent:x:175:
rpc:x:32:
rpcuser:x:29:
nfsnobody:x:65534:
munin:x:499:
screen:x:84:
scotty:x:999:
tquest:x:6382:
fuse:x:497:
httpfs:x:496:httpfs
knox:x:6383:
spark:x:6384:
hdfs:x:6385:hdfs
accumulo:x:495:
falcon:x:494:
flume:x:493:
hbase:x:492:
hive:x:491:
oozie:x:490:
storm:x:489:
```

While importing a table from sql server onto HDFS using Sqoop(**as the 'sqoop' Linux user**) :

```
ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=sqoop, access=WRITE, inode="/user/sqoop/.staging":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:319)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:292)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:213)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1771)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1755)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkAncestorAccess(FSDirectory.java:1738)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.mkdirs(FSDirMkdirOp.java:71)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3896)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:984)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:622)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2137)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2133)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2131)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:3010)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.mkdirs(DFSClient.java:2978)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$21.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1047)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$21.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1043)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirsInternal(DistributedFileSystem.java:1043)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirs(DistributedFileSystem.java:1036)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:196)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:169)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:266)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:673)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager.importTable(SQLServerManager.java:163)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:148)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:184)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:226)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:235)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:244)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied: user=sqoop, access=WRITE, inode="/user/sqoop/.staging":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:319)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:292)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:213)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1771)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1755)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkAncestorAccess(FSDirectory.java:1738)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.mkdirs(FSDirMkdirOp.java:71)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3896)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:984)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:622)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2137)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2133)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2131)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1427)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1358)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:558)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:3008)
        ... 28 more
```

While importing a table from sql server onto HDFS using Sqoop(**as the 'root' Linux user**) :

```
ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, inode="/user/root/.staging":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:319)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:292)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:213)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1771)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1755)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkAncestorAccess(FSDirectory.java:1738)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.mkdirs(FSDirMkdirOp.java:71)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3896)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:984)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:622)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2137)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2133)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2131)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:3010)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.mkdirs(DFSClient.java:2978)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$21.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1047)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$21.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1043)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirsInternal(DistributedFileSystem.java:1043)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirs(DistributedFileSystem.java:1036)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:196)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:169)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:266)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:673)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager.importTable(SQLServerManager.java:163)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:148)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:184)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:226)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:235)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:244)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, inode="/user/root/.staging":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:319)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:292)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:213)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1771)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1755)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkAncestorAccess(FSDirectory.java:1738)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.mkdirs(FSDirMkdirOp.java:71)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3896)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:984)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:622)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2137)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2133)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2131)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1427)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1358)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:558)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:3008)
        ... 28 more
```

**When I import a table from sql server onto HDFS using Sqoop(as the 'hdfs' Linux user), it works** but there is ONE error log statement

```
 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.3.2.0-2950
16/05/04 16:34:13 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
16/05/04 16:34:14 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
16/05/04 16:34:14 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
16/05/04 16:34:14 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM [DimSampleDesc] AS t WHERE 1=0
16/05/04 16:34:15 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/hadoop-mapreduce
Note: /tmp/sqoop-hdfs/compile/6f239d67662b5e2a3462b51268033d6e/DimSampleDesc.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
16/05/04 16:34:17 ERROR orm.CompilationManager: Could not make directory: /root/.
```

I have the following questions :

1. Why the error in spite of an auto. installation i.e I didn't skip any services/configurations
2. What is the ideal way to execute a Sqoop import or MR(I mean which respective users should be used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a home user (on HDFS) for the user who starts the command

When you start sqoop command, Hadoop will map the local user with an HDFS user, trying to locate the home which is /user/${USER.NAME}

As it appears that Hadoop super user is `hdfs` so you need to do :

```
$ su - hdfs 'hadoop fs -mkdir /user/sqoop'
$ su - hdfs 'hadoop fs -chown sqoop:hdfs /user/sqoop '
```

and then start sqoop as the user `sqoop`

Another alternative, is to change hive' staging directory to some other HDFS location where all users have write access to ( like /tmp)

in hive-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>hive.exec.stagingdir</name>
  <value>/tmp</value>
</property>
```

Comment: I have edited my question, can you check and help me understand ?

Comment: Yes exactly! when you starts the command as `hdfs` user, hadoop (or hdfs ) will execute the command as hdfs, and as the user `hdfs` has already its home on hdfs the request will pass... but with the user sqoop , it tries to use the home /user/sqoop, it could not find it , so trying to create it, and finds that sqoop have no permession to write on /user (owned by superuser `hdfs`) so the error happenned..... hope that will help

Comment: That works, now I have several doubts and one more issue but will post another question for that

Comment: I ve edited my answer, check it out , it might be useful in your case